# How to build C# without installing .net framework

Tags: c#

We have tens of building machines that could be old or new. We need to build the C# code with .Net 3.5, but not all the Windows machines have this version. We cannot install any software onto the building machines either. Is there a way to achieve this? We are OK to copy files to the building machines and delete them after the building it done. I tried to copy v3.5 folder to the build machine and neither msbuild.exe nor csc.exe works. I guess the .net framework has entries in the registry.

Comment: No, there is no reliable way.  You'll need to install the framework v3.5.

Comment: Why can't you just install the right tools on your build machines and be done with it?

Comment: is it a problem to update to .NET 3.5 on all build machines?

Comment: Don't know why this is getting down voted. It's a legitimate question.

Comment: @Mat Sometimes developers don't get the appropriate support they need. It's mind blowing. I know.

Comment: #2 Don't know why this has been closed as "not a real question". There's nothing ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical about it. A simple "no, can't be done" would've been the correct answer (I think).

Comment: If this needs to be closed, then the reason is wrong.

Comment: The question is "How do I do it?", not "Can I do it?"  There is no answer to "How do I do it?"

Comment: (@stmax: my vote was "too localized". The constraints listed are just not realistic: how do I `foo` when I can't use the tools you need to use to `foo`?)

Comment: @Mat imagine csc.exe being written in C and compiled to native code. It isn't, but that's not obvious (I had to check too), so asking a question is in order. After all if it was written in C, there might have been a way to just copy some files over and run csc to compile C# files without the .net framework being installed.

Comment: stmax, that is what I am looking for. Just copy some files onto the building machines and run csc.exe to build the C# code. I don't care how to run the C# executibles.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the correct version of the .NET framework on the build machines or it won't work.

Comment: Hi Jordan, this is problem I am facing and this is why I asked the question. I cannot install it on the building machine.

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately for you, it is impossible. That's like asking Visual Studio to run without installing Visual Studio.

Comment: as stmax said, I just want to copy some necessary files over to the building machines and run csc.exe to build the C# code. I don't care how to use the dll files. Is there a way to do it?